# Determining if scrolled to bottom of page in WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am working on scrolling a web browser control in a VB.NET application and was able to slowly, in code, scroll to the end of the document via a timer. What I would like to know is if there's a way to tell when I have scrolled to the bottom so that I can scroll back to the top to start things over again.

I have tried to check the height of the document, but it is only the height of my screen.  Is there a property that I can check to determine if I am at the bottom for scrolling purposes?

The way I am currently scrolling to the bottom of the page is:

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Timer2.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        scrollPos = scrollPos + 50
        WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, scrollPos)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to tell us how you are scrolling to the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if this solve your issue

```
Private Function IsBottom() As Boolean
    'return True if scroll reached body's bottom, else False
    Return (scrollPos >= WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height)
End Function
```

Comment: That worked, i just had to subtract the window height when doing the IsBottom check and it worked great.